# how do I put the results from an iteration into an array in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
a=[1 2 3 4
   5 6 7 8
   8 7 6 5
   4 3 2 1]

for i=(1:4)
b=(a(i,:));
c=sort(b,2)
end
```

Please, How can I obtain the results from this iteration in a single array(4x4) instead of getting the results of c=sort(b,2) separately for each loop.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a loop at all! You're trying to sort the columns in each row. This can be achieved by supplying an optional argument to `sort`.

```
c=sort(a,2);
c=
     1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8
     5     6     7     8
     1     2     3     4
```

should give you what you need. The argument `2` tells `sort` to sort `a` by columns. If you wanted to sort it by rows, you'd use `c=sort(a,1)`

Comment: am sorry, I only used this example code as an illustration. what I actually have is a more complex than this and 'i think' it has to be  in a loop. My question still is how to achieve putting the results in an array after about 1000 iterations?

Comment: well, if you _must_ use a loop, then preallocate `c` to `a`'s size by `c=zeros(size(a));`. Then fill in each row of `c` in the loop like so: `c(i,:)=sort(b,2);`